# Should the lightning-experience tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

It seems like the `lightning` tag covers this topic well, and is more heavily used than `lightning-experience`.

Answer (score 4):

No. Lightning Experience is a very specific UI Framework. Lightning encompasses a wide variety of features, including `Lightning Components`, `Lightning Process Builder`, `Lightning Connect`, and so on. LEX definitely deserves its own tag.

Comment: Not to mention that it's the new Salesforce "Marketing Speak". :)

Comment: But [tag:lightning] has a description that suggests it's an alias for [tag:lightning-experience], but is largely used as an adjective for other tags. This is tangentially related to my post about [tag:component].

Comment: Well that should be updated then because it's flat out wrong.

Answer (score 3):

[lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning) has been tainted as an adjective tag, and I'm not sure it's easily fixable. Ideally, lightning should be aliased to [lightning-experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-experience), but then we'll have to keep fixing people that are tagging lightning with other tags, like [service-console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service-console) and [lightning-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-components). We probably need some new tags, such as [lightning-service-console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-service-console), since there isn't feature parity with classic [service-console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service-console), which in turn should be aliased to [classic-service-console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-service-console). I think we've got an inherent problem with tags as they exist today, and we should start monitoring them more closely, and setting examples by correcting tags. I've done a lot more tag edits in the past two weeks than I have in the past two years, and we've really only just begun. By not keeping on top of the Lightning situation as it developed, we've accumulated a ton of tagging debt that needs to be paid sooner or later.